# Install Printer Usb Router

Tags: networking, usb, printing

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and connecting the printer directly via USB print perfectly but I want to have it connected to the USB port of my router and print through there, as I have in windows xp and from which it works perfectly.

I have searched information about it but im miss. Im trying adding as network printer or LPD URL SOCKET nor anything, in each case indicates to me a diferent state

Sorry for the Englih level.

Any idea?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

That's difficult, as routers normally want to install their software on connected computers, to enable priting via USB-Port. This fails, because probably it is a Windows Driver. Some time ago I also tried it and gave up finally.
Better would be, if possible, to connect your printer with a LAN-Cable to the router. Or you can connect the printer via USB to a computer and share it over the network. Thats easy, just go to System preferences - Printers - Add printer - On the network - Search. Connected printers should be found.

Comment: Thanks for de information, im going crazy, if i connect the printer direcctly to the laptop ubuntu find the driver and i can use it.

Comment: Thanks for de information, im going crazy, if i connect the printer direcctly to the laptop ubuntu find the driver and i can use it,so why do you say that is problmen of driver? i am writting mi direction 192.168.1.1:631 like windows xp include i follow quite tutorials about who add a printer which is conect to a router via USB